# White Noise Process

Tags: stochastic-processes

Suppose $w_{t}$ is a normal white noise process. Is $z_{t} = w_{t}*w_{t-1}$ stationary?

Is my reasoning correct?

$Ew_{t}w_{t-1}w_{t+h}w_{t+h-1} = 0 $
 for all $h$ implying that the series is stationary?

Comment: Reading this, one wonders which definition of "stationary" you are using.

Comment: I am using the weakly stationary definition. The mean and covariance are not function of time.

Comment: Then to check that $E(z_t)=E(z_tz_s)=0$ for every $t\ne s$ and that $E(z_t^2)=1$ for every $t$ seems rather straightforward, no?